# How to disable automatically set order status to 'Progressing' on Free Orders (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Iam making a simple e-commerce website using WooCommerce plugin on Wordpress. I am using BAC as my payment gateway and i have a **Non-price** ***(Free product)*** and have-price products.

When user is ordering *'Free Product'* from my store WooCommerce automatically change order status from '*pending*' to '*progressing*' (Because product have no price :), but I dont want to change status to 'progressing' just want to woocommerce keep '**pending**' status ***until i approve order***.

***How can i do that? Thank you so much for helping.***

The function should be for Non-price products. Should not affect have-pricing products.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below hook for change order status from process to pending again:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'filter_woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 10, 2 );
```

Check Link:
[woocommerce payment complete order status](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status/)

Comment: Hello @Ash Patel, thank you so much for your answer. Im ashamed to say that; i cant create a function for Non-price products :( I just wanna set non-price product orders status "pending" until i mark "complated". Do you have an idea for doing that? Thank yo again.

Comment: after use above hook inside function , just check condition for Free product and change status from 'processing' to 'pending' and return from function, it will set order status for free product in your database.